# Javascript OOP: should methods be enumerable?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, frameworks

I'm working on a new OOP model for JavaScript and I'm wondering whether you consider it right to make methods on objects enumerable or only the data members. I can see some sense in both and maybe there is no definite answer.

Can also make the own methods enumerable and the inherited ones not...

That said I feel it makes sense anyways to make all data members enumerable even if they are inherited.

**update**: this seemed not clear from what people are answering. I am creating a OOP model which will allow users to write something like this to declare a class:

**update 2**: in the mean time the project is out and about, this is what it has become: [OoJs](https://github.com/najamelan/TidBits_Javascript_OoJs). In it, user defined properties including methods are enumerable, properties added by the framework aren't.

```
;(function( namespace )
{
   'use strict';

       namespace.Shape = Shape
   var Static          = namespace.OoJs.setupClass( "Shape" )


   // Data members
   //
   Static.canvas = null


   Static.Protected( "canvas" )  // Protected members

   Static.Public   ()            // Public members


   // constructor
   //
   function Shape()
   {
      // Data members
      //
      this.sides = null

      // Private methods
      //
      this.init  = init


      this.Protected( "sides" )               // Protected members


      var iFace = this.Public( getOffset )    // Public interface


      this.init() // for example      


      return iFace
   }


   // Method definitions
   //
   function init     (){ /*do something useful*/   }
   function getOffset(){ return [ this.x, this.y ] }

})( window )
```

So the question is if you would use this to declare your classes, would you assume/want methods to be enumerable or not or should there be a way to configure either classwide or per member whether it should be enumerable not?

Comment: That's really up to the use case.

Comment: *What* sense can you see in that?

Comment: Do you say there should be syntax allowing the user to choose that when they declare a class?

Comment: @Bergi The sense I see in having them enumerable is that the will be a bit less obscured... and in having them not enumerable that I figure most of the time when looping over properties we are interested in the data rather then in the methods. Maybe the question is when you use `for in`, what do you use it for and would you prefer methods showing up or not?

Comment: Rarely do you need to iterate over object that is OOP object and not semantically being used as a dictionary. In fact serialization is the only thing that comes to mind and in that case it is more convenient just to define a `toJSON` method

Comment: Do you plan to provide special support for [harmony iterators](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:iterators) in user-defined classes when the next version of EcmaScript becomes widely available?

Comment: @MikeSamuel I haven't thought to much about ES6 because if all goes well it will have a class keyword and if we are really lucky that will support a similar featureset as c++ and custom oop models like this won't be necessary anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are some semantics associated with the keys -- you encourage users of your object to iterate over its properties -- then there's neither an advantage nor a disadvantage to having methods be enumerable.

You gain nothing by hiding them, and IDEs and other tools that interpret or partially evaluate your script can always use [`getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) to provide for auto-completion and the like.

> ## Object.getOwnPropertyNames
>
> Returns an array of all properties (*enumerable or not*) found directly upon a given object.

Comment: I updated the question to be more specific about what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

After consideration, Felix Kling's comment leads to the answer.

As it depends on the situation and since I don't know my user's situation, I shouldn't limit their options and at least offer a featureset as rich as the native Object model. I will allow for users to set options on their properties similar to [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

I think that **keeping the user's options open** should be considered an important programming principle, so this is not a hard decision.

The question remains over what the defaults should be. In standard javascript properties added to prototypes are all enumerable.